# await resp.prepare(request) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prepare'

Tags: python, attributeerror, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

```
async def index(request):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        data=await(email_verification(client))


        await client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/acc/signup',data=data)



async def email_verification(client):
    async with client.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c18dfb62f00005b00af1241') as resp:

        return await(resp.json())
```

but whenever i tried to acess the url  i got this error

```
   await resp.prepare(request)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prepare'
```

i cant even understand what the issue is  and where this resp.prepare came from  please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-handler should return a response object, not None.

The fixed code is:

```
async def index(request):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        data=await(email_verification(client))
        await client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/acc/signup',data=data)
    return web.Response(text="OK")

async def email_verification(client):
    async with client.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c18dfb62f00005b00af1241') as resp:
        return await(resp.json())
```